# How to convert FloatTensor to ByteTensor with Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm new to Pytorch and neural network programming but I've an issue I encountered and I'm not able to solve it on my own. My data are numpy arrays of 1 and 0. But when I try to train my net, I get this error :

> RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.ByteTensor but found type torch.FloatTensor for argument #2 'mat2'

the line where the error comes from is in the forward method of my net

```
x = self.fc1(x)
```

I've tried these to convert my tensors but I still get the error :

> x = x.type('torch.ByteTensor')

and

> x.byte()

Answer (score 5):

x.byte() returns what you need, but it's not an "inplace" method. Try doing:

```
x = x.byte()
```

Comment: Additionally, the other version he proposed works as well, but without the ' ' marks, i.e. `x = x.type(torch.ByteTensor)`

Comment: What are you getting? Could you provide perhaps more of your code?